# How to Remove (0) from String in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I wanted to format the string in XSLT-

Input  'ABC01312()wer**(0)**e66'

Expected output -  '0131266

I am using below code but here unable to remove**(0)**

translate($String, translate($String, '0123456789', ''), '')

Replace is not working, tried with  replace($TelephoneNumber,'(0)','')

Please help to remove **(0)**

Thanks

Comment: We can't infer a spec from a single example. We need to know what other strings might be encountered, and what the general rules are. Are you only trying to remove a "0" between parentheses, or might it be any digit? Might there be more than one "()" in the string? etc etc.

Comment: Don't tell us something "isn't working", tell us how it fails. What's the error message? A common reason for replace() failing is that you're using an XSLT 1.0 processor; if you told us the error message, we would be able to tell you the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(input, '\(0\)|[\D]', '')" />
```